# Laravel not receive mail from yahoo

Tags: email, laravel, yahoo

When I use yahoo.com email address to post a request through online form, the email address is not received anywhere - not a gmail or yahoo provided email accounts. When I put email address different from yahoo.com, the request is received to the destination address - no matter is it yahoo,gmail, etc.

```
Mail::send('emails.m_reservation', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
        $message->subject($data['name']);
        $message->to('gmail_username@gmail.com');
        $message->from($data['email'], $data['name']);
    });
```

No matter if the emails are received or not, the database contains the request, so it is written in it!

I use Laravel framework!
Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you check the spam folders?

Comment: As Tim said  have you check the spam? , i had the same issue , i suggest you to use a transactional email services for avoiding black list ..etc

Comment: Yes, I have checked all the spam and trash folders. Also black lists and etc. It is very strange problem. I have tested with more than 10 email domains, even local domains from Bulgaria and only with yahoo is not working especially when the poster of the form list his yahoo address. Thank you!